# Representation theory of Lie groups and outer automorphisms

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $G$ is a simply connected Lie group (I have in mind $G=SL_n(\mathbb{C})$), then we have an isomorphism
$Aut(G)/Inn(G)\rightarrow Aut(g)/Ad(G)$ induced by taking the differential at $1$; here $g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$, and $Aut(g)$ the group of Lie algebra automorphisms of $g$, and $Ad:G\rightarrow Aut(g)$ the adjoint representation of $g$. Now it is a fact that $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ has only **1** $2$-dimensional irreducible representation, whereas $SL_3(\mathbb{C})$ has **2** $3$-dimensional representations. Also for $G=SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ we have $\# Aut(G)/Inn(G)=\mathbf{1}$, whereas for $G=SL_3(\mathbb{C})$ we have $\#Aut(G)/Inn(G)=\mathbf{2}$. Surely this cannot be a mere coincidence; what is going on here? Perhaps one can use the number of irreducible representations to deduce the cardinality $\#Aut(G)/Inn(G)$?

Answer (score 2):

If $\varphi : G \to G$ is an automorphism of $G$, then given any representation $\rho : G \to \text{Aut}(V)$, we get another representation $\rho \circ \varphi : G \to \text{Aut}(V)$, which will generally be different if $\varphi$ is an outer automorphism. In particular the two $3$-dimensional representations of $SL_3$ are related by the nontrivial outer automorphism of $SL_3$ in this way. But a priori there could've been other unrelated representations of the same dimension.

Comment: +1 this is quite helpful. So for $G=SL_3$ you are saying that we get a bijection between $Aut(g)/Ad(G)$ and and the irreducible $3$-dimensional representations of $g$ by mapping $\phi Ad(G)$ to the composition of $\phi$ with the standard representation?

Comment: @Henri: I'm saying we get a map which happens to be a bijection, but in general I don't see a reason for the analogous map to continue to be a bijection.

Comment: I see, so if I want to prove in the case $g=sl_3(\mathbb{C})$, say, i need to use some structural properties of the lie algebra $sl_3$. Let's say I assume that there are only two $3$-dim reprs. Then to prove that our map is a bijection i need to prove: (a) the map is well-defined; (b) exhibit the nontrivial element of the domain (so it has cardinality at least 2), (c) prove that it is injective. (a) should be true in general, (b) I found out (its $x\mapsto -x^T$), and how should I approach (c)? Can we expect this to be true in general as well?

Comment: @Henri: you can try computing characters.